# How do I control Wordpress redirects?

Tags: theme-development

I have a page on a site I'm developing titled 'Athletics.'  If I mistype the url as /athletic (instead of /athletics), then my site redirects me to /events/athletic-banquet.  How can I control this behavior?

Comment: Perfect!  The other post answers my question.  Sorry for not searching this more thoroughly.